# Glide with wrap_content ImageView in Recycler View

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I'm using RecyclerView in a Fragment to list images. I use Glide library for images.  I read that: **Make sure the ImageView has match_parent or fixed dp as dimensions, wrap_content makes Glide load full resolution Bitmaps.** But I want to use wrap_content. Because when I use fixed dp some images have margin from left and right. Also horizantal images have margin from top and bottom. So how I replace these margins ?

xml:

```
<uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp" />
```

Code:

```
 ((Activity) Adapter.context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        deviceHeight = (int) ((displaymetrics.heightPixels) - ((displaymetrics.heightPixels) / 3));

        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = deviceHeight;


Glide.with(context).load(ApiClient.Base_URL + imagesList.get(0).getImage())
                            .dontAnimate()
                            .dontTransform()
                            .thumbnail(0.1f)
                            .override(deviceWitdh,deviceHeight)
                            .into(viewHolderSingle.postSingleImageView);
```

Comment: Have you tried .centerCrop() for Glide.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir yes but it crops the image. I need full images.

Comment: So, you use wrap-content and remove override(deviceWidth, ..). and use         android:adjustViewBounds="true" for imageView

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I also tried it but still recyclerview performance is very bad according to fixed height. :(

Comment: Do you know the ratio of the all images. Because the height and width of the image should be proportional with the ratio of the image

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir no I don't know and images have different ratios. Some images are vertical and some horizantal. Actually for vertical images there is no much problem but for horizantal images there is too much margin(blank space) from top and bottom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213577/discussion-between-kasim-ozdemir-and-mehmet-gur).